# $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\{|f|>n\}}f d\mu=0$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ an integrable function, then is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\{|f|>n\}}f d\mu=0$?

My attempt:

Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\{|f|>n\}}f d\mu=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\Omega}f I_{\{|f|>n\}} d\mu$

Define the sequence $f_n=f I_{\{|f|>n\}}$.

Since $f_n$ converges pointwise almost everywhere to $0$, then using the *Dominated Convergence Theorem*, we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\{|f|>n\}}f d\mu=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\Omega}f_nd\mu=\int_{\Omega}0d\mu=0$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Without an additional assumption, it's false (e.g. $f(x) = |x|$).  Where in the proof do you use this additional assumption?  I.e. You've not justified one step properly

Comment: @BrianMoehring, which assumption?

Comment: @BrianMoehring, Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ an integrable function, then is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\{|f|>n\}}f d\mu=0$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring, does this proof only work for $L^1$?

Comment: yes this is correct, and $|f|$ is the dominating function. And yes, without the assumption $f\in L^1$, this could fail.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Is there a counter example for $f\notin L^1$

Comment: look at the very first comment in this thread.

Comment: @peek-a-boo would the value be infinite in this case?

Comment: yes (filling up spaceeee)

Comment: @peek-a-boo, Thank you. Just one last question. In a previous multiple choice exam question we were asked if $f\in L^1$ and $\int_{\{|f|>n\}} d\mu=\lambda$ Then is the value of $\lambda=0$ or $1$ or $\infty$. Since the limit is not included in the integral, then of course $\int_{\{|f|>n\}} d\mu=\mu({\{|f|>n\}})$. But how does this equal a constant? Shouldn't the answer depend on $n$?